# What is Objective C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

What is Objective C++ and can I use this language in Xcode?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Objective-C++ is simply source code that mixes Objective-C classes and C++ classes (two entirely unrelated entities). Your C++ code will work, just as before, and the resulting executable will be linked with the Objective-C runtime, so your Objective-C classes will work as well. You can definitely use it in Xcode -- name your files with the `.mm` extension.

Also, you might want to read [Apple's (sadly deleted, but archived) documentation on Objective-C++](https://web.archive.org/web/20101203170217/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html).

Comment: the limitation section in that link says this and is worth quoting _Objective-C++ does not add C++ features to Objective-C classes, nor does it add Objective-C features to C++ classes. For example, you cannot use Objective-C syntax to call a C++ object, you cannot add constructors or destructors to an Objective-C object, and you cannot use the keywords this and self interchangeably. The class hierarchies are separate; a C++ class cannot inherit from an Objective-C class, and an Objective-C class cannot inherit from a C++ class. In addition, multi-language exception handling is not supported_

Answer (score 42):

Objective-C++ is Objective-C (probably with Cocoa Framework) with the ability to link with C++ code (probable classes).

Yes, you can use this language in Xcode to develop for Mac OS X, iPhone/iPodTouch, iPad. It works very well.

You don't have to do anything weird in your project to use Objective-C++. Just name your Objective-C files with the extension **.mm** (instead of **.m**) and you are good to go.

It is my favorite architecture: develop base class library of my game/application in C++ so I can reuse it in other platforms (Windows, Linux) and use Cocoa just for the iPhone/iPad **UI** specific stuff.

Comment: Its not about *linking* with C++ - did you mean *mixing*?