# iOS:Is it correct to use bitset<100> b; in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to use `bitset` in **iOS** just like C++?
Or how can I use `bitset` in **iOS** coding?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it compile? Does it link? Does it run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The principal development language for iOS is Objective-C, which can't use C++ types.

However, you can add C++ sources to your projects or use [Objective-C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684112/what-is-objective-c-and-can-i-use-this-language-in-xcode) (which allows you to mix Objective-C and C++) and hence use `std::bitset`.