# how to declare int array[] as a property in appDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, int

Is it possible to declare a int array property in app delegate?

```
int myArray[12];
```

Comment: No you can't, but you can use Objective-C++ structures. Then you will be able to use std::vector structure. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684112/what-is-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C does not support C array properties.

Your best option is to use an `NSArray` property instead. If you really need a C array to be accessible from outside, use an `int *` property and a `size_t count` property for the number of elements.