# How to add LittleEndian Pitch Detector SDK to Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, pitch-detection

I am trying to add the [LittleEndian Pitch Detector SDK](http://www.littleendian.com/developers/meterworx-pitch-detector-sdk/) to Xcode project. However, I am getting errors after adding the development static libraries and header files to the project.

Steps I did were,

1. Downloaded the LittleEndian Pitch Detector SDK
2. Drag and drop the static libraries available in the libs/development to the project
3. Drag and drop the include folder to the project
4. Set the user header search paths in the build settings to the include folder
5. Add the   #import "pitchDetector.hpp" after the #import "ViewController.h"

[image]

after that I am getting 3 errors

[image]

Comment: Did you find any documents for adding this SDK?

Comment: Vishnu, SDK documentation is available in the /doc directory.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460871/how-to-use-littleendians-pitch-detector-sdk-to-detect-pitch.

Comment: @Danijel I am the original user who asked the question on 15 April 2015 and the link you are stating is the duplicate one, and that guy also using the screenshot from my question. have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To include an .hpp file in an Objective-C implementation, change the `ViewController.m` to `ViewController.mm`; you're living in [Objective-C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684112/what-is-objective-c) land now!

(Note: This is still important in a Swift-based project, since we'll need Objective-C wrappers to be able to call these library functions from Swift.)