# Create directory/file in iOS using C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c++

Is it possible to create in app's home dir (Documents or Library) dir/file using C++ code? I tried `system()` and `posix_spawn()`, which work on Simulator, but fail or real device (eg. running `mkdir`). Core Foundation methods seem to give only read, not write possibility too.

**Edit**

In addition to answer below my simplified implementation of tar.gz unpacking using C++/Core Foundation [here](https://github.com/schmidt9/date) (ios.h/ios.mm)

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://mobile.antonio081014.com/2013/06/create-rename-delete-read-and-write.html) will help? It is objective-c I think.

Comment: @aichao yes, but I am looking for c++ solutions, not ObjC

Comment: It has been a while since I developed for iOS, but can't you link to any obj-c/c++, c/c++ code in building the app?

Comment: @aichao Not sure I understand what you mean, simply google "Objective C++"

Comment: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684112/what-is-objective-c) is what I mean.

Comment: @aichao Ok, and what now? :)

Comment: Use that Objective-C code in your app. It is not going to write itself :-)

Comment: @aichao Ah, I got it. Sure I know all this solutions, I have a c++ library and thought not to mix ObjC and C++, leaving only C++, my question is if I can do things you pointed with C++, not ObjC. But now I almost sure, it is impossible, Apple does not let use shell commands like tar or mkdir in C++ code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120967/discussion-between-aichao-and-schmidt9).

Comment: Thanks! Great to see that you have the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the home directory using the Core Foundation library's [CFCopyHomeDirectoryURL() function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1620446-cfcopyhomedirectoryurl?language=objc). (This is a C function, no Objective-C required.) Using the CFURL accessors, you can pull the path from that and use it with standard C++ or C/POSIX file I/O functions. Or you can use Core Foundation for I/O directly.

You can't used `posix_spawn` or `system` or `fork/exec*` in iOS due to sandboxing. No shell scripts either.

Comment: Yes, thanks to @aichao I used `mkdir` from `sys/stat.h` to create directory, and for tar unpacking I'll write custom code

Comment: You may be able to use whatever open source tar handling library OS X and FreeBSD uses.

Comment: I need only unpacking `tar.gz`  that's why I do not want overhead with shipping a whole lib

Comment: I don't know how big that library is, but you could probably pare it down to just extraction. Tar isn't a terribly complex format, but there are probably a few edge cases, and file parsing is always a security risk. Anyway, whatever works best in your case!