# Get NSHomeDirectory() in pure C

Tags: c, objective-c, nsstring, nshomedirectory

I am trying to get the `NSHomeDirectory()` in pure C

```c
#include <CoreFoundation/CFBundle.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

void testFunc() {
    printf(NSHomeDirectory()); 
}
```

Comment: And what's your problem?  It's not a good way of using `printf()` — you would be safer using `printf("%s\n", NSHomeDirectory())`, but it's unlikely to be your problem.  Is the problem occurring when you compile the code, when you link the code, or when you run the code?  You should probably mention that you're trying to work on macOS X, and presumably, you're using Xcode — but are you using the IDE or just the command-line tools?

Comment: `CFCopyHomeDirectoryURL()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create directory/file in iOS using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945963/create-directory-file-in-ios-using-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the `UTF8String` message to the `NSString` object returned by `NSHomeDirectory()` to obtain a C string. To do this in pure C (Tested):

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <objc/message.h>
void *NSHomeDirectory();
void testFunc() {
    puts(((const char *(*)(void *, SEL))objc_msgSend)(NSHomeDirectory(), sel_getUid("UTF8String")));
    // Also use puts() instead of printf() here
}
```

***Note:** Compile using `-framework Cocoa`*

Comment: @Mohab If you `NSLog(NSHomeDirectory())` in Objective-C what do you get?

Comment: I just get "/Users/mohabhisham/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7B0A58B1-92DD-4C1E-9544-53BC319D6AB1/data/Containers/Data/Application/7F7BBF73-A6E2-410C-B83A-0DF29D152A05"

Comment: with your code it prints extra stuff

Comment: @Mohab Cannot reproduce. What system are you using? And what happens if you try `NSLog(NSHomeDirectory().UTF8String)` in Objective-C?

Comment: it prints the same "211" thing

Comment: @Mohab Whoops I mean try `puts(NSHomeDirectory().UTF8String)` from Objective-C