# How to compile Objective C++ in GCC?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, objective-c++

I installed GNUStep and `gobjc` in Ubuntu 16.04. I can compile Objective-C code like this:

```
gcc codefile.m `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lobjc -lgnustep-base -o codefile
```

But I want to compile Objective-C++ code in GCC. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Documentation of objc/objc++ dialects in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Objective-C-and-Objective-C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#Objective-C-and-Objective-C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options) of your [version of gcc / gobjc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/devel/gobjc) don't list specific option to select the dialect variant.

Just use standard file extension ".mm" or ".M" (additionally you can replace `gcc` with `g++` to automatically add C++ libraries into linking stage; both variants untested):

```
gcc codefile.mm `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lobjc -lgnustep-base -o codefile
g++ codefile.mm `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lobjc -lgnustep-base -o codefile
```

And ObjC++ is ["simply source code that mixes Objective-C classes and C++ classes"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3684159)

Gcc will select mode based on file extension, there is huge table of file extensions and corresponding language modes with Objective-C for `.m` and Objective-C++ for `.mm`/`.M`: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-4_7_4-release/gcc/gcc.c#L913

```
static const struct compiler default_compilers[] =
{
  /* Add lists of suffixes of known languages here.  If those languages
     were not present when we built the driver, we will hit these copies
     and be given a more meaningful error than "file not used since
     linking is not done".  */
  {".m",  "#Objective-C", 0, 0, 0}, {".mi",  "#Objective-C", 0, 0, 0},
  {".mm", "#Objective-C++", 0, 0, 0}, {".M", "#Objective-C++", 0, 0, 0},
  {".mii", "#Objective-C++", 0, 0, 0},
 . . .
  /* Next come the entries for C.  */
  {".c", "@c", 0, 0, 1},
```

There is also `-x` option of `g++` with allowed argument of "objective-c++" to manually select language dialect (`gcc -x objective-c++ ...` or `g++ -x objective-c++`):
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1cb6c2eb3b8361d850be8e8270c597270a1a7967/gcc/cp/g%2B%2Bspec.c#L167

```
case OPT_x:
 . . . 
      && (strcmp (arg, "c++") == 0
      || strcmp (arg, "c++-cpp-output") == 0
      || strcmp (arg, "objective-c++") == 0
```

It is documented at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html

> ```
>  -x language
> ```
>
> Specify explicitly the language for the following input files (rather than letting the compiler choose a default based on the file name suffix). This option applies to all following input files until the next -x option. Possible values for language are:
>
> ```
>       c  . . .  c++ . . .
>       objective-c  objective-c-header  objective-c-cpp-output
>       objective-c++ objective-c++-header objective-c++-cpp-output
> ```

Comment: My experience with Objective-C++ is limited to macOS, but the file needs to be named with extension .mm, otherwise it won't work. I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: @osgx Thanks for your detail information. I could compile Objective-C++ with `g++` like this: ``g++ codefile.mm `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lobjc -lgnustep-base -o codefile``.

Comment: @H.Al-Amri With clang on macOS you can use the `-ObjC++` flag when compiling. This will override the filename based mode detection.