# Project language in Xcode when building an C++ static library project

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to create a new Cocoa Touch Static Library project in Xcode which will build C++ source code. But when asked in the project settings for a language selection. I am hesitating, the choice is between Objective-C and Swift languages.
Is the choice of project language when building c++ static library is important?

Answer (score 0):

Choose Objective-C. Objective-C works better with C++ than Swift does. See the following Stack Overflow question:

[What is Objective C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684112/what-is-objective-c)