# How to get GLUI to work on macOS using Xcode?

Tags: macos, xcode

I downloaded GLUI from https://github.com/libglui/glui, but I am not clear on how to get it to work on my Xcode. I read this step:

> To include GLUI in your own apps, add the glui library to your makefile (before the glut library 'libglut.a'), and include "glui.h" in your sources.

1. Where would I find my makefile since I am using Xcode?
2. I was able to get #include to compile, but if I try GLUI *glui from the manual, I get "Unknown type name 'GLUI'". There is something on the front page: https://lukecyca.com/2008/glui-235-framework-for-mac-os-x.html where it mentions #include, but I don't know where I can get GLUI/glui.h.

Answer (score 2):

After you build the lib, you'll have two directories `lib` and `include` which you have to move to your Xcode project. It'll look like this:

[image]

If Xcode does not see the includes nor links to the library, you'll have to add them to search paths (headers and libraries) like so:

[image]

NOTE: In order to use them in Obj-C you'll have to change file extension to `.mm` (obj-c++ file).

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify which are the obj-c++ files that need to have .mm extensions?

Comment: @friendofmario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684112/what-is-objective-c here are some explanations. You have not specified what language you are using, I assumed Objective-C, that's why I've added that note about obj-c++

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using C++.