# Compiling lambda as Objective-C++ causes block cast

Tags: clang, clang++, objective-c++

I have a non-copyable C++ lambda which captures a unique_ptr, and certain situations when compiling with Apple Clang as Objective-C++ cause the lambda to get converted to a block pointer, at which point the compilation fails due to an attempted copy of the lambda. A simple example is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{   
    std::unique_ptr<int> myHeapInt = std::make_unique<int>(4);
    int myStackInt = 0;

    auto myLambda = [&, myHeapInt = std::move(myHeapInt)]()
    {
        myStackInt = *myHeapInt;
    };

    if(bool(myLambda)) //Error ar this point
    {
        *myHeapInt = 5;
    }

    std::invoke(myLambda);

    return 0;
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'const lambda...
Implicit capture of lambda object due to conversion to block pointer here
```

Is there a way around this conversion?

Comment: Why is it that you think you can just mix and match C++ and Objective-C++? They are *different languages*.

Comment: [Apparently you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684112/what-is-objective-c), but this looks like pure c++.

Comment: Yes I know they are different languages, I am trying to make something compatible with both.

Comment: Rajveer, it is not a good idea to mix two languages. It is easier to make and manage two versions with "copy paste and adjust". Dropbox tried to make C++ based code for their mobile app (so it would work on both iPhone and Android) and came to conclusion that it is a bad idea. Now they just write two versions one for Android on Kotlin and one for Apple (on whatever language it natively uses... Swift?).

Comment: It's perfectly fine mixing C++ with Objective-C, this is what Objective-C++ is.

Comment: @Rajveer but if std::function doesn't compile can you really call it successful?

Comment: This isn't std::function, it's a std::function replacement which allows customisations such as supporting non-copyable lambdas.

Comment: `std::function` IIRC accepts non-copyable lambdas.

Comment: Just checked it - it doesn't accept it but there is a simple work around by wrapping the lambda. Google it, there is an answer on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

What is that `bool(myLambda)`? I have no clue.

The only thing you can do with a lambda is evoke it: `myLambda()`. You cannot test for whether it exists or anything.

Comment: Technically you can cast a lambda to `bool` *if* it has no captures, because it can decay to a function pointer which can then convert to `bool`.  However, to do so is pointless, because you can never have a falsy lambda.

Comment: I am using a std::function replacement (https://github.com/Naios/function2) that used to compile fine as Objective-C++ but now fails to. This replacement does bool conversion as part of some optimisation, which is where it now fails since the lambda is converted to a block.

Comment: Same result unfortunately, Clang still tries to convert this to a block pointer.

Comment: @Rajveer I mean not just the bool cast but the if entirely.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not entirely seeing the relevance of Objective-C++ here, as this code doesn't compile as C++ either:

```
objc++-noncopy-lambda.cpp:15:9: error: cannot convert '(lambda at objc++-noncopy-lambda.cpp:9:21)' to 'bool' without a conversion operator
    if (bool(myLambda))
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

The error message is different; I assume there's some attempt at implicitly converting lambdas to blocks in Objective-C++, I've tried to stay away from weird edge cases like that, but it seems that in the absence of an `operator bool` it might try the conversion to a block first.

Either way the code you're attempting to write doesn't make any sense and the compiler is correctly rejecting it.

I see in the comments that you're actually trying to do something different. Could you perhaps post a reduced version of the code you're actually trying to write, which supposedly compiles as C++ but not as Objective-C++?

Comment: What is your environment and what are you compilation options? My example works fine when compiled as C++17 with Clang, and the actual library compiles fine on MSVC, Clang and GCC (also compiled as C++17). It's not easy to create a reduced version because it's a templated header-file class, that's why I created the example above as that is the exact part that is failing. Essentially the class implements a vtable, which it optimises if the callable implements operator bool() or can be converted to bool.

Comment: Anyway I've found that this is by design in Clang for blocks and lambdas to be interoperable (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#interoperability-with-c-11-lambdas) so I've just decided to disable this optimisation if compiled as Objective-C++.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to compile a templated header-file class replacement for std::function ([github.com/Naios/function2](https://github.com/Naios/function2)) as Objective-C++, which implements a vtable and optimises it if the callable implements operator bool() or can be converted to bool.

In the end I just decided to disable this optimisation if compiled as Objective-C++ as converting to a block pointer is by design in Clang for block-lambda interoperability (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#interoperability-with-c-11-lambdas).